# Using fixed numbers

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, numbers

I was just wondering how to make a never changing number when called at the start of the script ?

So once you have defined it from the Awake() or `Start()` how can i make it so the number is fixed ? Even functions can't change it.

I don't want to provide a definite number, like 2 or 5 or 100 or even 1000000 I want to make a variable so i can change it in the `Awake()` or `Start()` function. And keep it fixed throughout the whole script.

Is that possible?

Comment: You probably just need to make it a [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) field.

Comment: There's something a little flawed with your question. You want the method "Awake" or "Start" to set a field that cannot be set by a method. If you want it to be set in the constructor, then you can use readonly or if you want it defined at build-time, then you can make it const. However, if you want it set in a method, then it has to be a normal writable field.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is you can't do this with how you described, the closest thing you can do is use a readonly field and a constructor

```
public class Foo
    {   
        public readonly int myInt;   
        public Foo()
        {
            myInt = 1;
        }

        public void doBad()
        {
            myInt = 1213; // Not allowed
        }
    }
```

You can do the following if you absolutely needed to, but BEWARE THIS IS A HORRIBLE PATTERN AND DOES NOT ENSURE THAT IT WAS SET ONLY BY START. YOU SHOULD NOT DO THIS!!!!!

```
public class Foo2{
    private bool calledOnce = false;
    private int _myInt;
    public readonly int myInt{
        get {return _myInt;}
        set {
            if (calledOnce){
                throw new Exception("Not allowed");
            }else{
                _myInt = value;
                calledOnce = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        myInt = 1213;
    }

    public void doBad()
    {
        myInt = 1213; // will throw
    }
```

In case the big capital letters weren't obvious, doing the second thing is a very poor idea, and reflects a lot of problems in the code, and will likely be the source of strange bugs, but once in a blue moon there is a need for some horrible strange code to handle a very odd problem, but I'm guessing that this isn't one of those cases. Best to rethink the entire problem and better understand what the real requirements are.

Comment: There absolutely *shouldn't* be a case where the latter option is preferable. If OP is writing all their code themselves, they can make smart design decisions that avoid coding pitfalls.

Comment: Your first example will not work too well in Unity3D.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it in the `Awake()` or the `Start()` then by that logic what you want is a constant variable. Since you can't pass parameters to those two functions then by that logic the variable should be constant and its value known at compile time.

```
const int WHAT_WANT = 11011;
```

Also it is not safe to use constructors when the class is a `MonoBehaviour`. Therefore `readonly` is a terrible idea.

(ps Awake and Start implies OP is using a MonoBehaviour)